# How to get ajax result and display it on another page?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, codeigniter

I want to get the results from the API, and display them on another page. But I am confused about how to get the result and save it in the php function.

```
$.ajax({
    url: '<?php echo base_url('sistem/check'); ?>',
    type: 'POST',
    data: {   
           code: code,
           id: id
          },
    cache: false,
    success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
             console.log(textStatus + ": " + jqXHR.status);
             console.log(data);
             var y = JSON.parse(data);
             var x = y.data.id;
             console.log(y.data.id)
             if (y.status !== 0){
                window.location.href = "<?php echo base_url('sistem/detail/'.encryption('x').''); ?>";
             }else{
             $('.response').html(y.message);
             }
             },
     error:(e) =>{
                    console.log(e.responseText);
                 }
           });
```

this is the result

```
{
   "status":1,
   "message":"allowed to access detail",
   "data":{
      "id":"007",
      "code":"code",
      "detail":"lorem opsum",
      }
}
```

function detail in controller

```
public function detail($id){
     $id =  decryption($id);
     $this->load->view('sistem/detail');
}
```

i want to get the result in detail function. But i dont know how to do. Thank You

Answer (score 0):

Copy the codes from your 'sistem/check' controller which is getting the results and put it in 'sistem/detail' controller so that you can get the result whatever your 'sistem/check' is getting.

Comment: this still doesn't work because there is data that must be entered on the previous page.

Comment: What if you include the data in the parameters when you redirect the page? so that you can execute the codes you copied from 'sistem/check' controller.